# Download, edit and reupload FTP file with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to get a server.cfg file from a FTP in a form on my website, using PHP. After this I want to edit the server.cfg file on the website, click 'submit' and reupload the edited file  on the FTP. I did some research, but I still get some errors. I've managed to get the file in the form: http://elmazmx77.seventyseven.axc.nl/gameservers2.php . But if I edit and save the form, I get errors. My PHP Code:

```
<?php

$config = array 
( 
'user'  => 'Hunterr', 
'pass'  => '[PASSWORD]', 
'domain'    => 'ycn-hosting.com:21', 
'file'      => '213.108.31.167-27030/etpro/server.cfg',       # relative to 'domain' 
); 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$fp = fopen($config['file'],'w'); 
fwrite($fp,stripslashes($_POST['newd'])); 
fclose($fp); 

$ftp = ftp_connect($config['domain']); 
ftp_login($ftp,$config['user'],$config['pass']); 
ftp_pasv($ftp,TRUE); 
ftp_put($ftp,$config['file'],$config['file'],FTP_BINARY); 
ftp_close($ftp); 

} 
?> 

<form width="440" height="440" method="post" action="<?=( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] )?>"> 
<textarea name="newd"><?=(       file_get_contents('ftp://'.$config['user'].':'.$config['pass'].'@'.$config['domain'].'/'.$co    nfig['file']) )?></textarea> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"> 
</form>
```

Any idea's? (You can see the errors yourself here: http://elmazmx77.seventyseven.axc.nl/gameservers2.php) Line 13 starts at:  $fp = fopen($config['file'],'w'); so you know where the errors come from.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

as the error message states "Warning: fopen(213.108.31.167-27030/etpro/server.cfg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory" you're trying to open a file that is not there. The file is not in the directory your script is running in. Use an absolute path or correct relative path to the server.cfg file.

You might want to add some checks in there too, to see if the fopen command actually succeeded.

gl

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Well I am quite sure the directory is good. Also, the file 213.108.31.167-27030/etpro/server.cfg IS opening in the form... You can see it yourself here: http://elmazmx77.seventyseven.axc.nl/gameservers2.php

Comment: You are filling the textarea by opening the file over ftp. Seems to me it's located in the root directory of that account. Your script file however is in a directory 'public_html'. So try adding "../" to the fopen command:

$fp = fopen("../" . $config['file'],'w');

Comment: So I just edit the code to: $fp = fopen("../" . $config['file'],'w'); ? If I do that I get the same errors.

Comment: try using absolute paths then